# Including XML comments – Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Xml comments not showing up

I'm following the example of:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

My code looks like this:

```html
var baseDirectory = System.String.Format(@"{0}bin\", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var commentsFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".XML";
var commentsFile = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, commentsFileName);
c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Documentação web Api");
```

In my DefaultController
[image]

```html
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register a new user on application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">New user to register</param>
    /// <remarks>Adds new user to application and grant access</remarks>
    /// <response code="400">Bad Request</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("consulta/BuscaProduto")]
    //localhost:50907/api/consulta/BuscaProduto
    public HttpResponseMessage BuscaProduto()
    {
        try
        {
            var tTabela = new ProdutoAplicacao();
            var listar = tTabela.ListaTodos();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listar, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just struggled with this problem recently :)

Swashbuckle will not automatically generate a 200 success response, which contains the model and example value, if any response is explicitly specified.

In your case, since you specified a "400" and "500" response, Swashbuckle expects you to also specify the "200" response. I think you have 2 options:

1. Specify the 200 response in the XML comments for each endpoint in which other responses are specified
2. [Add the 200 responses programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170456/automatically-generate-default-200-ok-response-while-specifying-other-response-t/45176336#45176336) using an operation filter in SwaggerConfig