# Automatically generate default 200 OK response while specifying other response types

Tags: c#, api, swagger, swashbuckle

According to [#216](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/216), Swashbuckle will automatically generate a 200 success response as the default behavior, or otherwise expects all response types to be specified.

I'd like to be able to add a 404/400 error response to some endpoints in the XML comments while keeping the 200 success responses for all endpoints, including those with a 404/400 error response.

Is it possible to make Swashbuckle continue to automatically generate a 200 success response for all endpoints even when an error response is specified?

Edit: I added an operation filter to programmatically add the missing 200 responses, which resolved the missing model schemas, but still doesn't really answer my original question about whether there's a way to keep Swashbuckle's automatic generation of 200 success responses

```
class CustomOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var responses = operation.responses;
        if (responses.ContainsKey("404") || responses.ContainsKey("400"))
        {
            responses.Add("200", new Response()
            {
                description = "OK",
                schema = (schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType))
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not without noodling in Swashbuckle itself. For what it is worth, your solution is quite handy, you should consider posting that as a self-answer/workaround.  Maybe more generally just check that responses do not contain key "200"?

Comment: Thanks! Just changed the check to see if the responses do not contain the key "200." I had to add an extra check to make sure the ReturnType isn't null before adding a 200 response to avoid an exception as some endpoints (like Delete) do not return anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround to add missing 200 success responses to endpoints that have specified error responses:

```
class CustomOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var responses = operation.responses;
        if (!responses.ContainsKey("200"))
        {
            if (apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType != null)
            {
                responses.Add("200", new Response()
                {
                    description = "OK",
                    schema = (schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType))
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```